# Why am I not getting the audio file form the front end react to python server

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

This is the React code:

```
import React ,{ ChangeEvent, useState } from "react"

const FileUpload: React.FC = () => {
    const [selectedFile, setFile] = useState<File| null>(null);
    

    const HandleAudioChange = (event:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const file: File | null = event.target.files?.[0] || null;
        setFile(file)
        // console.log("Selected file", file)
    }

    const UploadAudio = () => {
        if(selectedFile){
            const formData : FormData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file',selectedFile)

            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload', {
            method:'POST',
            body:formData,
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log("Server response", data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("This is the error ", error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log("File has been uploaded")
        })
        }

        
    }
    

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center mx-auto">
    <input className="rounded-full bg-white bg-opacity-70 text-xs text-blue-600 uppercase font-SF sm:px-3 font-semibold hover:shadow-md  sm:py-3 mx-auto" type="file" accept="audio/*" onChange={HandleAudioChange} />
    <button  onClick={UploadAudio}>
        
    </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FileUpload
```

and this is the python server code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_audio():
    try:

        audio_file = request.files["file"]
        # Process the audio file as needed
        # For example, save it to disk or perform analysis
        return jsonify({"status": "success", "message": "Audio received successfully"})
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify(
            {
                "status": "error",
                "message": "No audio file received",
            }
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you can help me, I would really appreciate it!
The audio file is uploading and it's showing in the console

I tried to get the audio file from the server but I am not getting the files

This is the Python response:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might not be uploading because you may not have the `enctype` attribute specified in the form, according to the snippet below from the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.files).

> Note that **files** will only contain data if the request method was POST, PUT or PATCH and the `<form>` that posted to the request had `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It will be empty otherwise.

I see you're not using the `<form>` component at all, so that might be where the issue lies.